# Why could not find the android.widget.gallery class? how to fix it?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-gallery

There is a error which displays the XML. It says:

> The following classes could not be found:
>
> - Gallery (Change to android.widget.Gallery, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

The `gallery.java` exists in the widget file. Why is there a error, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, I thought I put my 2 cents into it.
Gallery is deprecated.

Use ViewPager. A nice tutorial in here.
http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Eclipse then go to Project tab and clean the project. Then refresh it. Try running it again. It should fix the issue.

Comment: Have you got any result from this?